# Error in starting of wso2esb-4.8.0 server

Tags: java

I have Configured JAVA_HOME and CARBON_HOME properly in windows7, When I try to run the server I am getting bellow error. 
I had restarted my system couple of times still I am getting the same error.
I tried removing CARBON_HOME from environment variable still getting the same error. Please help me out.

D:\Program Files\wso2esb-4.8.0\bin>wso2server.bat  --run
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\Program Files\wso2esb-4.8.0
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\wso2esb-4.8.0\repository\conf\carbon.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is "whitespace characters" . Remove whitespace from classpath or surround with " chars.

Comment: Changed the wso2esb-4.8.0 folder location .... Now I am running from D:/wso2esb-4.8.0 and it is working fine.